# HighMaps Undefined ZoomTo()

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have problem with my high maps when rendering, i currently using zoomTo() function to zoom region in my country (PHILIPPINES). when i using that it return me an "Cannot read property 'zoomTo' of undefined". I see some developers using it. but when i apply it on my code it returns me an zoomTo undefined.

im using Jquery 3.2.1.min.js

[This is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsvuP.png)

[This is my code (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7q3U.png)
[This is my code (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRPKy.png)

Comment: Please add your code and error here in text format instead of linking images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get` method uses the `id` option to find an element, so to use it with `zoomTo`, you need to add `id` to some point. Below you can find fully working example with `get` and `zoomTo` methods:

```
document.getElementById('zoomTo').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chart.get('EE').zoomTo();
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zob490v8/

API:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point.html#zoomTo

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#get

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.data.id

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the get method. got an idea on how i will do it . you're so great!